# Creating a map in HTML, CSS, SVG?

Tags: html, css, svg

I would like to create a web based regional map that would enable the user to click in order to choose a region on the map, and will also have some visual effect (resizing, etc) when hovering over one of the regions.

I want the map to work on desktops and mobile devices.

I'm having doubts regarding the best technology to use here when I'm mainly considering traditional image maps vs.SVG.

Image map are more widely supported, but any animation that effects only a single area in the map must be hacked over. SVG is a more natural fit, but is not supported by Android (old IEs can work using svgweb)

Any advice? Any other option I'm overlooking?

Comment: I did look at his/her page before commenting (always do). The user "could' accept a few answers as well as participate more in his/her questions via comments. The running theme here is that he/she asks a question and leaves it at that.

Comment: @rockintthesixstring - I thank you for your criticism. I'll try to be a better SO citizen in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have your answer; you are offering the option between SVG and image maps, say that you need mobile support, and say that Android doesn't support SVG. SVG is thus eliminated, and you are left with image maps.

Comment: Thanks! I guess you're right. I'll go with an image map and maybe switch to SVG if at some point Android supports it by default.

Answer (score 0):

Android and any other mobile OS that wants to remain competitive will almost certainly be [enabling SVG in their default browsers](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1376) eventually, as there is basically no good reason not to.

If you truly cannot wait, however, there's this:
http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/css/slopes